# PHP, Magento, issue with overriding file

Tags: php, magento

I want to override core file (core/Mage/Catalog/Product/List.php). How should look like the path to override it in app/code/local using companyName/extensionName/?.

Comment: Yes, but do not forget to create rewrite node ih your `config.xml`

Comment: Ok, but how the path should look like? That's my problem, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are going to override the file - app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php

Either you can direct override it by coppying at

```
app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php
```

path OR you can override it using **rewrite** in config.xml and stored it at

```
app\code\local\COMPANYNAME\EXTENSIONNAME\Block\Product\List.php
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please check below link, i think it'll help u.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_a_local_copy_of_app_code_core_mage

Answer (score 0):

Just Mention Below code in your config.xml

```
<blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_list>Namespace_ModuleName_Block_Catalog_Product_List</product_list>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
</blocks>
```

and also create file inside Block Folder

The Path of Block will be Catalog/Product/List.php

and just write below code in List.php

}

Hope it will serve your purpose.